# how to change Extended floating action button Icon by code?

Tags: android, icons, floating-action-button

i have an [Extended Floating Action Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/)  that i want to change icon programatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`setIconResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#setIconResource(int)) method

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
extendedFloatingActionButton.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
```

Comment: would you plz look at my another Q?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024952/viewpager-instantiateitem-methods-error-and-not-able-to-inflate-layout-in-fra

Answer (score 1):

`ExtendedFloatingActionButton` class descends from [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java), so you can control the icon which is displayed using [`setIcon()`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java). So you can do:

```
extendedFab.icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)
```